# How to render plugin shortcode through api in mobile app?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created API using Wordpress REST API from that API I am sending Wordpress post content to the mobile app.I have added forms and polls plugin to add different forms and polls in posts.The problem is that the shortcode for that forms and polls is not working when I pass it to mobile through API. So how can I render that shortcode to the mobile app?

Comment: can you give brief description for this i don't understand your question.

Comment: I created WordPress plugin & in that, I am using shortcode for forms & poll plugin in Wordpress post, then Using Wordpress REST API I am sending the list of posts to mobile apps, every other HTML tags & component parse correctly in webview but shortcode is not parsing mobile webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use **iframes** to display the shortcode.

For example :

1. Create a page with the shortcode in it.
2. Then use this page url as the src of the iframe.
3. And show this iframe where you need on your mobile app.

One disadvantage can be the loading time, use a loader if needed but otherwise it should do the trick.